# How to reference a local variable inside the definition of a function?

Tags: local-variables

Is it possible to reference a local variable inside the definition of a function? Here's an example:

I have an alist `text-alist` consisting of keys and text snippets. I want each text snippet bound to a key in the prefix map `my-text-prefix-map`. The code below doesn't work, I guess because when the functions in `my-text-prefix-map` are run, the value of `text` is unknown. Is there any way to remedy this?

```
(mapc (lambda (text)
        (define-key my-text-prefix-map (kbd (car text))
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (insert (cdr text)))))
      text-alist)
```

Comment: Do some searching for "closure". You should find many duplicates and approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use backquotes and commas to build functions dynamically:

```
`(lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (insert ,(cdr text)))
```

Or you can also enable lexical-binding to make function closures.

More information on Backquotes can be found in [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, please leave a comment explaining why. Using a backquote is a very common solution to the problem.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I would like to see actual code for the lexbind case which, IMHO, should be the first and preferred suggestion.

Comment: The lexbind solution uses the exact code in the question, just with a `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` on the first line (a comment) of the file.